# What exactly is the output of window.print()?

Tags: javascript, printing, dom-events

(Obviously if I had a printer handy I would test this and find out!)

I am wondering what exactly the Javascript function window.print() will print when used on a page where content has been edited since first rendered in the browser window.

By this I mean, for example, if a HTML list was produced and the user then 'removed' certain items by clicking a button which executed Javascript to remove the elements via `fadeOut()` or `remove()`, would printing the page produce a copy of the current state or the original static version?

Sorry if this is worded poorly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.print()` will print the page as it currently appears, modified only by applying any `@media print` rules, which can be seen on the Print Preview. Actually, having written that, just select File => Print Preview and you should see what will be printed if you had a printer.

Comment: All these years and I never noticed a Print Preview option! That said, apparently I need a printer installed to access it. I should have printers installed on another laptop here though so that will do.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the browser, but I just tested it out in the console and it will in fact print the content of the page as-is (that is it does not reload the page to do the printing).  So if you do some DOM manipulation on the page and use `window.print()`, and most likely the normal file > print, removed items won't show.

Answer (score 0):

It will open a print preview of what is currently displayed on the page at that moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old and I can understand availability of tools at that time...
Now, we can install a pdf printer like 'foxit' and output the pdf to see what we get.